# How can I look at the SQL statement that produced an ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm getting this exception when I try to update one of my models:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "id"
LINE 1: ...M "options" WHERE "options"."product_id" = $1 AND "id"."name...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  "options".* FROM "options" WHERE "options"."product_id" = $1 AND "id"."name" = $2 LIMIT $3
from /Users/mikeyhew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.beta2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:634:in `prepare'
```

Using this exception, how can I see the full SQL query that was invalid?

Comment: Look deeper to your stack trace to see what happen? And where does this query come from?

Comment: Well I could post my code, but it's not really relevant to the question - I was trying to figure out **what the invalid sql query was**. I managed to find it, and I'll post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I managed to find the invalid sql statement: I opened the file where the exception was coming from, and put a debugger statement on the line right before the exception is raised.

I was hoping that either the StatementInvalid exception or the PG::UndefinedTable exception would have the actual sql code as one of their instance variables, but that wasn't the case.